# Inserting large amounts of data to Mongoose & ElasticSearch via Mongoosastic

Tags: node.js, mongodb, elasticsearch, mongoosastic

I am following these instructions:
https://www.compose.com/articles/mongoosastic-the-power-of-mongodb-and-elasticsearch-together/

I have a TSV file (17MB) that I am iterating through. I am watching my Indexed results with the following code:

```
Entry.on('es-indexed',(e,r)=>{
      console.log(`Indexed Result: ${r}
        Indexed Error: ${e}`);
    })
```

Some of my data is getting indexed properly, but I get many error messages too:

```
Indexed Result: undefined
        Indexed Error: Error: Request Timeout after 30000ms
```

Here is my model.js file

```
const ChebiName = new mySchema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    es_indexed: true
  },

  id: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  }
});

ChebiName.plugin(mongoosastic);
module.exports = mongoose.model('ChebiName',ChebiName);
```

Comment: Do you see any ES errors in the ES console / Kibana?

Comment: there were some warnings about 90% of my memory being used, so it was switching nodes. No errors.

Comment: Did you try increasing your jvm heap limit?

Comment: how did you fix this ?