# MongoDB get best match - Is this possible?

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have fulltext enabled with MongoDB. Here is my script:

```
function bestMatch(name){
  ChebiEntry.find({$text: {$search: escapeString(name)}},
  {score: {$meta: 'textScore'}}, {lean:true},(e,results)=>{
    if (results.length > 0){
      let oneScores = []
      results.forEach((obj)=>{
        if(obj.score===1){
          oneScores.push(obj);
        }
      });
      console.log(oneScores);
    }
  })
  .sort({score: {$meta: 'textScore'}})
}
//prepareDatabase();
bestMatch('K+');
```

And here is my output:

```
[ { _id: 596d55fd2c446456a0cebc1d,
    id: 8345,
    name: 'K+',
    __v: 0,
    score: 1 },
  { _id: 596d55ff2c446456a0ceccb2,
    id: 8345,
    name: 'K(+)',
    __v: 0,
    score: 1 },
  { _id: 596d56072c446456a0ceee6b,
    id: 29103,
    name: 'K(+)',
    __v: 0,
    score: 1 },
  { _id: 596d56072c446456a0cef092,
    id: 29104,
    name: 'K(-)',
    __v: 0,
    score: 1 } ]
```

I have a hit that is verbatim what I searched. However it has the same score as several other hits that are not exactly what I searched. This 'score' system that mongoDB is not very helpful like this.

Is there a way to change this score system to give verbatim matches a higher score? There are also results that are over 1, which are even worse hits for my query.

Comment: Just a note - MongoDB's fulltext search is very lacking, in my experience, in terms of both features and performance. For more advanced usage, you might want to take a look at [this module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoosastic), which can index your text field using ElasticSearch, which can yield much better results than MongoDB alone.

Comment: @nadavvadan, Thank you. I tried that solution actually. But I found it impossible to insert large amounts of data into mongoosdb and have it sync with elasticsearch w/o a million time out errors (local).

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45155361/inserting-large-amounts-of-data-to-mongoose-elasticsearch-via-mongoosastic

Comment: That is odd, I've used mongoosastic with 100Ks of long text documents, with no timeouts. Something might be wrong with your configuration! this is off-topic however.

Comment: MongoDB text search does have a bonus for exact match of search terms but the overall relevance score depends on your search criteria and indexed fields. Can you include examples of your text index creation, documents, and search criteria? Also, what specific version of MongoDB are you using?